# Cut string into substrings with PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm looking to cut a string after at a character and then create many substrings from that string. I have a variable like this:

```
$pizza = "slice 1, slice 2, slice 3, slice 4, slice 5, slice 6";
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>slice 1</li>
  <li>slice 2</li>
  <li>slice 3</li>
  <li>slice 4</li>
  <li>slice 5</li>
  <li>slice 6</li>
</ul>
```

How would I do something like that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: And then just loop through the array and print out your list items

Comment: I tried using `explode`, but that's only for arrays -- I have a string... Right?

Comment: No. Explode explodes an string into an array.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like this with a [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop and [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) like this:

```
$pizza = "slice 1, slice 2, slice 3, slice 4, slice 5, slice 6";

$slices = explode(',', $pizza);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($slices as $slice) {
  echo '<li>' . trim($slice) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The way it works is [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will take the string `$pizza` and create an array of slices called `$slices`. Then via a [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, each `$slice` will be processed as a string. And since you have whitespace in the string, [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will clean it up so each slice is clean.

Now if you wanted to get a bit fancier, you could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) like this:

```
$slices = preg_split("/[,]+\s*/",  $pizza);
```

That will split the string into an array via a regex that splits based on commas & empty spaces. And since it is matching commas with extra spaces, the resulting array should already be clean & trimmed. So this should work:

```
$pizza = "slice 1, slice 2, slice 3, slice 4, slice 5, slice 6";

$slices = preg_split("/[,]+\s*/",  $pizza);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($slices as $slice) {
  echo '<li>' . $slice . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$pizza = "slice 1, slice 2, slice 3, slice 4, slice 5, slice 6";
$sliceThatPizza = explode(',',$pizza);

echo '<ul>';

foreach($sliceThatPizza as $slice){
   echo '<li>'.htmlspecialchars(trim($slice)).'</li>';
   }

echo '</ul>';
```

Using `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` for your output is good practice. Especially when presenting data from a database. And `trim` is used to get rid of unnecessary spaces in the beginning and at the end of a string.

Here's the manual about how `explode`,`htmlspecialchars` and `trim` works for your reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner:

```
$pizza = '<ul><li>' . preg_replace('/, /', '</li><li>', $pizza) . '</li></ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the explode()  function.

```
$sliceArray = array();
$sliceArray = explode(',',$pizza);
```

You may need to remove extra spaces from each slice string, in which case use trim() on each string:

```
foreach ($sliceArray as $slice){
    $slice = trim($slice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below:

```
    $pizza  = "slice 1, slice 2, slice 3, slice 4, slice 5, slice 6";
    $slices = explode(",", $pizza);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($slices as $slice) {
       echo "<li>" . trim($slice) . "</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Just did some minor changes as what is given in example in the manual [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)